# How to download sources for a jar with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar

In my project I am using a JAR file provided via Maven. But what Maven gives me is only this jar - no javadocs and no sources. Pressing "Download Sources" has no effect: Eclipse still does not find the sources of the jar.

What this depends on? Should repository provide sources automatically?

May be I need to write something in POM to instruct Maven to download sources?

My current pom follows:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>xuggle repo</id>
        <url>http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
        <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
        <type>rar</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Why Maven does not say any comments on it's sources download fail?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

**2020 Update:**

The [maven dependency plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/3.1.1) should be used whit the `dependency:sources` [goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html):

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>download-sources</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>sources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This can also be run from the command line as:

```
mvn dependency:sources -Dsilent=true
```

Executing `mvn dependency:sources` will force maven to download all sources of all jars in the project, if the sources are available (are uploaded in the repository where the artifact is hosted). If you want to download javadoc the command is `mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc`

**Deprecated:**

It's also possible to create a profile in your settings.xml file and include the following properties:

```
<properties>
  <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
  <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
</properties>
```

Comment: But if there are no sources in repository Maven will just do nothing silently, right? No errors, no warnings?

Comment: yes, I suppose so, at least if it's not running in some very verbose/debug mode. Maybe it's possible to run it in debug/verbose mode and grep for the specific messages.

Comment: I added an answer to extend on the adding of these properties to the maven settings.xml

Comment: @hovanessyan - Can we add some setting which pulls jars only for some of the dependencies rather than all of them ?

Comment: can these properties be part of project properties?

Comment: These properties are for the deprecated Eclipse Maven Plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#downloadJavadocs). They won't do anything if you're not using that plugin.

Comment: the xml snippet <properties> etc. etc. put inside my settings.xml and against a profile has not worked for me - this might allude to what @AndrewBourgeois was trying to explain

Comment: Note: The first paragraph under **Deprecated** is still valid and should not be struckthrough, but the edit queue is currently full.

Comment: @Leponzo done - I've removed the strikethrough

Comment: @hovanessyan, thanks, but the second paragraph is still deprecated and can be struck through, while the first paragraph can additionally be moved out of the Deprecated section.

Comment: @Leponzo got it, thanks.

Answer (score 64):

```
mvn dependency:sources
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

if it does not have sources it should say something like

```
[INFO] The following files have NOT been resolved:
[INFO]    com.oracle:ojdbc6:java-source:sources:12.1.0.1
[INFO]    javax:javaee-api:java-source:sources:6.0
```

Answer (score 15):

It is best not to rely on the Eclipse plugin as it is deprecated. Using the `downloadSources` and `downloadJavadocs` properties did not work for me.  The answer posted above regarding the use of the dependencies plugin word.  However, you may wish to automatically download sources and javadocs.  Furthermore you may wish to always create a source jar and a javadoc jar.  Put this in the pom of your project. If you use modules, put in your parent pom.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- download sources and javadoc -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>download-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>download-javadoc</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resolve</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Always create javadoc jar. -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadoc</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Always create source jar. -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I agree with @AlmirCampos

Answer (score 7):

In eclipse, rigth click on your project then `Maven>Download Sources` again `Maven>Download Javadoc`

Answer (score 6):

You can also download sources under `target/dependencies` using:

```
mvn -Dclassifier=sources dependency:copy-dependencies
```

Answer (score 4):

The source/javadoc jars may not have been provided and are not in the repository -- there is nothing that requires a source/javadoc jar to be present.

Answer (score 4):

extending on @hovanessyan answer.

A basic profile for enabling the downloadSources and downloadJavadocs, in Maven's settings.xml will look like this. 
e.g. profile id is downloadSources

```
<!-- add the profile under profiles section -->

    <profile>
        <id>downloadSources</id>
        <properties>
            <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>           
        </properties>
    </profile>

<!-- activate the profile under activeProfiles section -->

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>downloadSources</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```